# split or subset data into 30 minute intervals

Tags: r, time, split, subset

I have a data frame of the following form:

```
Temp    Depth      Light   x   time date                   time.at.depth
104     18.59      -2.7    27 21:38 2012-06-20             4
109     18.59      -2.7    27 22:02 2012-06-20             5
110     18.75      -4.0    27 22:07 2012-06-20             5
113     18.91      -2.7    27 22:21 2012-06-20             4
114     18.91      -4.0    27 22:26 2012-06-20             5
115     18.91      -2.7    27 22:31 2012-06-20             5
117     18.91      -2.7    27 22:40 2012-06-20             4
118     18.75      -4.0    27 22:45 2012-06-20             5
119     18.75      -2.7    27 22:50 2012-06-20             5
121     18.59      -4.0    27 22:59 2012-06-20             4
122     18.75      -2.7    27 23:04 2012-06-20             5
123     18.75      -4.0    27 23:09 2012-06-20             5
126     18.59      -2.7    27 23:23 2012-06-20             5
127     18.59      -2.7    27 23:28 2012-06-20             5
128     18.59      -4.0    27 23:33 2012-06-20             5
133     18.75      -4.0    27 23:57 2012-06-20             5
136     18.59      -4.0    27 00:11 2012-06-20             5
138     18.59      -2.7    27 00:21 2012-06-20             5
140     18.91      -2.7    27 00:30 2012-06-20             5
```

I would like to subset the data into 30 minute bins. Is there an easy way to do this? I looked at the `split()` function but it appears that things need to be in a numeric format for that to work, I have time in `POSIXct` format. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the cut() function?

Comment: This looks relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528571/aggregate-count-occurences-of-values-over-arbitrary-timeframe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a one-liner for you (`dat` being your dataframe):

```
split(dat, cut(strptime(paste(dat$date, dat$time), format="%F %R"),"30 mins"))
```

Indeed `cut.POSIXt` accepts as break values

> an interval specification, one of "sec", "min", "hour", "day", "DSTday", "week", "month", "quarter" or "year", optionally preceded by an integer and a space, or followed by "s".

Additionnaly, I used `%F %R` as a shortcut for `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M`: see `?strptime` to see all possible formats.

Comment: As a bit of warning though, in the example you gave, if it is meant to be in the correct order, your values past midnight should be changed to `2012-06-21` otherwise they would be incorrectly translated by `strptime`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly to separate the data into 30 min intervals. Is there a way using 'apply()' or another function to find the mean and standard error of the temperature during each interval?

Comment: Use `lapply`. For instance if you save the results of my answer as `res`: `lapply(res, function(x)mean(x$Temp))` or `lapply(res, function(x)sd(x$Temp))`.